# How to refactor native Android Java method to be called from React Native?

Tags: java, android, react-native

I currently have the following activity which is created when my app starts and is declared as an activity in my AndroidManifest.xml:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<activity android:name=".IncomingActivity"></activity>
```

IncomingActivity.java:

```java
package com.xyz;

import android.os.Build;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class IncomingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
            setShowWhenLocked(true);
            setTurnScreenOn(true);
        }
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_incoming);
    }
}
```

I now want to be able to use this functionality on demand from React Native. I have refactored it like the below so far but when this native method is called, I just get a blank white screen and I think the problem is this line: `activity.setContentView(mReactRootView);`

Updated class:

```java
public class UnlockDevice extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "UnlockDevice";
    }

        private ReactContext mReactContext;
        private ReactRootView mReactRootView;

    public UnlockDevice(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
                mReactContext = reactContext;
                mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(reactContext);
    }

    /* React Methods */
   @ReactMethod
    public void Unlock() {
                    Activity activity = mReactContext.getCurrentActivity();

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
                    activity.setShowWhenLocked(true);
                    activity.setTurnScreenOn(true);
                }
                
                activity.getWindow().addFlags(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN 
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON 
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);

                activity.setContentView(mReactRootView);
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to be able to call this method to toggle the functionality but with the main activity instead of starting a new one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Explanation

Basically, you missed 2 things - you didn't register your `UnlockDevice` in a `ReactPackage`, and you didn't add your `ReactPackage` to the list of packages in the application.

Also, don't forget that your native method will not be executed on the UI thread with **React**. So, it's your responsibility to run it there. For example, by using `runOnUiThread()` as below:

```
...
    @ReactMethod
    public void Unlock() {
        Activity activity = mReactContext.getCurrentActivity();

        activity.runOnUiThread(() -> {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
                activity.setShowWhenLocked(true);
                activity.setTurnScreenOn(true);
            }

            activity.getWindow().addFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
            activity.setContentView(mReactRootView);
        });
   }
...
```

So, first create a `ReactPackage` class to register your module.

#### MainReactPackage.java

```
public class MainReactPackage implements ReactPackage {
   @Override
   @NonNull
   public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(@NonNull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
       return Collections.emptyList();
   }

   @Override
   @NonNull
   public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(
           @NonNull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
       List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();

       modules.add(new UnlockDevice(reactContext));

       return modules;
   }
}
```

Then, add the latter to the list of packages in your `Application` class.

#### YourApplication.java

```
 ...

 private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
      new ReactNativeHost(this) {
        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          packages.add(new MainReactPackage());
          return packages;
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
          return "index";
        }
      };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }
...
```

### Full code

For a reference, I created a sample project similar to yours that works just fine. Below is relevant code.

#### MainActivity.java

```
package com.reacttest;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript. This is used to schedule
     * rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "ReactTest";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

#### MainActivityModule

```
package com.reacttest;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;

public class MainActivityModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

    private ReactContext mReactContext;
    private ReactRootView mReactRootView;

    public MainActivityModule(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        super(reactContext);
        mReactContext = reactContext;
        mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(reactContext);
    }

    @ReactMethod
    public void helloFromAndroid() {
        Activity activity = mReactContext.getCurrentActivity();
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
                    activity.setShowWhenLocked(true);
                    activity.setTurnScreenOn(true);
                }

                activity.getWindow().addFlags(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
                activity.setContentView(mReactRootView);
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Hello from Android", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "MainActivityModule";
    }
}
```

#### MainActivityPackage.java

```
package com.reacttest;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ViewManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


public class MainReactPackage implements ReactPackage {
    @Override
    @NonNull
    public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(@NonNull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(
            @NonNull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
        List<NativeModule> modules = new ArrayList<>();

        modules.add(new MainActivityModule(reactContext));

        return modules;
    }
}
```

#### MainApplication.java

```
package com.reacttest;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;

import com.facebook.react.PackageList;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

    private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost =
            new ReactNativeHost(this) {
                @Override
                public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
                    return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
                }

                @Override
                protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
                    List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
                    packages.add(new MainReactPackage());
                    return packages;
                }

                @Override
                protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
                    return "index";
                }
            };

    @Override
    public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
        return mReactNativeHost;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
        initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
    }

    /**
     * Loads Flipper in React Native templates. Call this in the onCreate method with something like
     * initializeFlipper(this, getReactNativeHost().getReactInstanceManager());
     *
     * @param context
     * @param reactInstanceManager
     */
    private static void initializeFlipper(
            Context context, ReactInstanceManager reactInstanceManager) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            try {
        /*
         We use reflection here to pick up the class that initializes Flipper,
        since Flipper library is not available in release mode
        */
                Class<?> aClass = Class.forName("com.reacttest.ReactNativeFlipper");
                aClass
                        .getMethod("initializeFlipper", Context.class, ReactInstanceManager.class)
                        .invoke(null, context, reactInstanceManager);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### App.js

```
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';

var mainActivityModule = NativeModules.MainActivityModule;
mainActivityModule.unlockScreen();
```

#### Result

[image]

As you can see, the Toast from the `Activity` is shown. That's it!